# Jquery Messing with Variables

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
if (firstTime !== true) {
        $('#forecast-table2').removeClass('bounceInLeft').addClass('bounceOutRight').one('webkitAnimationEnd mozAnimationEnd MSAnimationEnd oanimationend animationend', function(){
            outputWeather(weather, "under");
            $(this).removeClass('bounceOutRight').addClass('bounceInLeft');
        });
    } else {
        outputWeather(weather, "under");
    }
```

The first `outputWeather()` doesn't work as it's supposed to but the second one does. The first one is giving an error when it runs saying that it can't set the property of undefined. .I'm guessing that the variable `weather` is being reset or something when passed into the first `outputWeather()`. How would I make the first time `outputWeather()` is called work the same as the second? Thanks.

Also, here is the `outputWeather()` function:

```
function outputWeather(weather, source) {
if (source === "under") {
    var tableNumber = 2;
    $("#weather-location2").html(weather.region);
} else if (source === "yahoo") {
    var tableNumber = 1;
    $("#weather-location1").html(weather.city + ', ' + weather.region);
}
if (tableNumber !== 1) {
    $('#tod-pop'+tableNumber).html(weather.pop+'%');
    weatherAvg.data.pop.push(weather.pop);
}
$("#tod-temp"+tableNumber).html(weather.temp);
weatherAvg.data.temp.push(weather.temp);
}
```

The issue occurs on line 11 (`weatherAvg.data.pop.push(weather.pop);`).

Here us `weatherAvg`:

```
var weatherAvg = {};
weatherAvg.data = {precentop: [], temp: [], high: [],low: [], wind: {speed: [], direction: []}};
```

Comment: where are you getting `weatherAvg`?

Comment: What "doesn't work" about it, please can you be a little bit more specific with your problem.  As well as the question above, your tableNumber is set locally to the if and else if, so the following if will always be true as it will never be 1